# Are there any MVC web frameworks for Haskell?

Tags: model-view-controller, web-applications, networking, haskell, web-frameworks

Are there any MVC web frameworks for Haskell?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645168/comparing-haskells-snap-and-yesod-web-frameworks

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-write-web-apps-in-haskell/5695847#5695847

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may be worth looking at the Yesod framework:

http://docs.yesodweb.com/

which takes some of the concepts found in MVC web frameworks fitted in modern and idomatic Haskell.

Comment: Thank Cristiano. Yesod is very interesting project.

Comment: I would be surprised if Yesod used MVC. How does it achieve observing models from within views?

Answer (score -3):

2 seconds... Google... http://github.com/alsonkemp/turbinado/wiki

Comment: More or less abandoned, I believe. The consensus seems to be that the approach was not a good fit for Haskell.

Comment: @Daniel Pratt: Sounds like Alexey is barking up the wrong tree then.

Comment: Thank you Lazarus. I also find turbinado, but posted this question to find all existing projects.

Comment: Alexey, make sure you mention such things in your question. The more specific you are the less likely you are to get answers like mine ;)

Comment: @AdamWagner If I thought the question deserved a fuller answer then I would have presented it. My answer is very specifically tailored to the question.