# Templating packages for Haskell

Tags: haskell, templating

What are some preferred packages for templating in Haskell. Something similar to Django Templates, or PHP.

I don't want to always use it with HTML. It can be any other thing. I guess what I want is a string interpolation library, that also supports loops, registration of filter/escape utilities, if conditions, etc.

Comment: Not necessarily. This was for a little project that generates Kindle-compatible .mobi files (incidentally they're HTML and XML files). But I have other uses cases where a structured markup language is not involved.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to the Hackage popularity statistics, the top three packages, by far, are (2014):

1. (29,000 downloads) [shakespeare](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shakespeare) -- replacement for hamlet.
2. (27,816 downloads) [hamlet](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hamlet) -- yesod framework templating
3. (10,625 downloads) [heist](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/heist) -- snap framework templating
4. (7099 downloads) [HStringTemplate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HStringTemplate) -- general purpose templating

You can see more about these two systems in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645168/comparing-haskells-snap-and-yesod-web-frameworks).

Comment: Be aware that both of these are specific to HTML/XML.

Comment: Actually, HStringTemplate still leads the pack by a healthy margin with 4463 downloads. And it isn't html/xml specific either :-)

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I wanted some more generic than just HTML/XML.

Comment: Hamlet says it's deprecated in favor of [shakespeare](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shakespeare).

Answer (score 32):

Some related packages:

- [Bravo](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Bravo) - Static text template generation library
- [chunks](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/chunks) - Simple template library with static safety
- [halipeto](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/halipeto) - Haskell Static Web Page Generator
- [hamlet](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hamlet) - Haml-like template files that are compile-time checked
- [hastache](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hastache) - Haskell implementation of Mustache templates
- [heist](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/heist) - An xhtml templating system
- [HStringTemplate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HStringTemplate) - StringTemplate implementation in Haskell.
- [Interpolation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Interpolation) - Multiline strings, interpolation and templating.
- [PCLT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/PCLT) - Extension to Show: templating, catalogizing, languages, parameters, etc.
- [press](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/press) - Text template library targeted at the web / HTML generation
- [template](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template) - Simple string substitution
- [twine](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/twine) - very simple template language

Comment: Thanks for the list. Twine and Hastache look quite nice.

Answer (score 3):

hastache seems rather well designed imo. Bravo is a cool idea, but suited for what I want (loops, etc.), and it assumes all parameters are, in some way or another, strings.

Answer (score 3):

[interpolatedstring-perl6](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/interpolatedstring-perl6) provides a simple and well designed Quasiquoter to produce interpolated String/Text from Templates containing arbitrary Haskell  expressions.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [karver](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/karver) ([github](https://github.com/sourrust/karver)) package, not mentioned in other answers. Author says “its syntax is heavily inspired by Jinja2”, but “it isn't as full featured or production ready as Jinja is”.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that karver [uses partial functions for error handling](https://github.com/sourrust/karver/issues/7), so it is unsuitable for use cases where users input the templates.