# Using html files as templates in happstack

Tags: haskell, templating, happstack

I can find plenty of documentation on using blitz and other compiletime templating libraries with happstack but I would like to know how to use html files as templates.

Comment: See the answers to this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5770168/371753

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though there are many options, my favourite would be `Heist`, which would allow you to define a `splice`:

```
> factSplice :: (Monad m) => TemplateMonad m Template
> factSplice = do
>   input <- getParamNode
>   let text = T.unpack $ X.nodeText input
>       n    = read text :: Int
>   return [X.TextNode $ T.pack $ show $ product [1..n]]
>
```

which could be used in a dynamic (loaded at runtime) `HTML` template:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Factorial Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Factorial Page</h1>
    <p>The factorial of 6 is <fact>6</fact></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

To use `heist` in `happstack`, you'll need the [happstack-heist](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-heist) package. For more detail and other options, see [**Using Heist**](http://happstack.com/docs/crashcourse/Templates.html).

Answer (score 0):

The HStringTemplate package provides a very general runtime templating system for not only HTML, but any sort of text output:

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HStringTemplate/0.6.6/doc/html/Text-StringTemplate.html

The HStringTemplate package integrates with Happstack nicely through a few extra instances provided by an optional package: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-hstringtemplate