# Activating HTML with Haskell

Tags: html, web-applications, haskell

I have a large pile of lecture notes in raw HTML format. I would like to add interactive content to these notes, in particular incorporating online exercises. I have some experience implementing online exercises as cgi-bin executables compiled from Haskell code running on the server, interacting with a student record file and sending suitable HTML back to the browser, using `Text.Xhtml` to generate the content. Now I plan to integrate the notes and the exercises.

The trouble is that I don't want to spend ages manually transforming my raw HTML into Haskell code to generate exactly the raw HTML I started with. Instead, I'd like to put my Haskell code and my HTML in the same source file, with placeholders in the latter for content generated by the former. A suitable tool should then transform this file into Haskell source code for (e.g.) a cgi-bin executable which generates the corresponding page.

Before I go hacking up such a piece of kit, I thought I'd ask if there's better technology out there already. The fixed points are the large legacy lump of HTML, the need to implement the assessment of the exercises in Haskell, and the need to interact with student records on the server. The handicap is that I need to use the departmental web server and I can't reconfigure it (ok, maybe I could ask nicely): that's one of the reasons I currently use cgi-bin executables, which are just fine on our server already, but I'm open to other possibilities.

My current plan is to write a (I mean adapt an existing) preprocessor to support a special syntax for defining functions of type

```
Html -> ... -> Html -> Html
```

that looks a lot like raw HTML with splice points. Then what I do with my existing raw HTML is indent it a bit and mark the holes.

But would that be a waste of time? Please, please tell me that this question is a duplicate!

Comment: By way of mechanically extracting Haskell source from my legacy HTML, blaze-from-html is looking promising, modulo some unicode niggles.

Answer (score 3):

There are Haskell frameworks like Yesod and Happstack which use templating engines like you describe.

Have you looked at the haskell wiki at http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HSP or 
http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Web/Libraries/Templating ?

They may do what you need.

Comment: HSP sounds good. Links to documentation seem broken, and I could use some examples. But it's certainly worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

You might find someting to do the job here: [Templating packages for Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770168/templating-packages-for-haskell).

And you should probably look into Snap, Yesod or Happstack for serving the content.

Comment: I probably can't run my own web server. Will that cause a problem with Snap, Yesod or Happstack?

Comment: Those frameworks do need you to run a server _somewhere_. [Reverse proxying](http://www.google.no/#hl=en&gs_nf=1&cp=10&gs_id=12&xhr=t&q=reverse+proxy) is the new cgi-bin.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a large pile of lecture notes in raw HTML format. I would like to add interactive content to these notes, in particular incorporating online exercises.

There is already a system (called "ActiveHs"), written in Haskell, that allows to put lecture notes and interactive exercises in one file.

See:
http://pnyf.inf.elte.hu/fp/UsersGuide_en.xml
http://pnyf.inf.elte.hu/fp/Constructive_en.xml

I can really say that it is very well written code and completely open source!