# What is the current state of the art in Haskell web frameworks

Tags: model-view-controller, haskell, frameworks

I am looking for insight into the the current state of the art in Haskell web frameworks.

What I would consider to be necessary for a good framework:

- web application interface for connecting to http servers (like Rack)
- chainable middleware (again, like Rack or node.js Connect)
- idiomatic Haskell
- solid performance
- reasonable docs or at least readable open-source code

The framework does not necessarily need to be a full MVC stack, an elegant DSL for routing and handling requests (think Sinatra) would be more than sufficient.

Some of the options I have found:

- [Snap](http://snapframework.com/)
- [Yesod](http://yesodweb.com)
- [Miku](https://github.com/nfjinjing/miku)
- [Bird](https://github.com/moonmaster9000/bird)
- [Happstack](http://happstack.com)

I like the depth of experience in the Haskell world to really make an informed decision, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing Haskell's Snap and Yesod web frameworks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645168/comparing-haskells-snap-and-yesod-web-frameworks)

Comment: @DanBurton there are several alternatives as well as Snap and Yesod, there is at least 1 similar question but is outdated and lacks detailed analysis.

Comment: and people voting as not constructive, how on earth are you meant to make decisions about how to approach a new language framework if you can't ask for reasoned, impartial analysis from the community?

Comment: SO is not the community to ask such questions.

Comment: @TobyHede - The "big three" are Yesod, Snap, and Happstack; so the similarity to the Snap/Yesod question seemed clear to me. If nothing else, the information in those answers should be useful to you. I think the "not constructive" votes are because you are asking a very broad and somewhat vague question. I'd suggest trying to gather information from irc (#haskell, #snapframework, #yesod), from /r/haskell, and mailing lists.

Comment: You may be interested in reviewing http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Web/Frameworks

Answer (score 4):

My impressions

**Snap**

- 144 Watchers
- 31 Forks
- active development community
- early stages of development
- great documentation
- "snaplets" feel like servlets, seem quite heavyweight

Yesod

- 147 Watchers
- 27 Forks
- seems to be largely a single committer
- great documentation
- seems complicated and monolithic (includes among others forms, templates, and an orm)

Miku

- 8 Watchers
- 1 Forks
- seems to be largely a single committer
- lightweight - inspired by Sinatra
- minimal documentation

Bird

- inactive project
- wonderful dsl (my pick as most "sinatra-like")
- minimal documentation

Happstack

- ?