# Is it possible to use Hamlet with closing tags?

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

Is it possible to use the Hamlet templating library but still write end tags? I'm uncomfortable with the idea of significant whitespace in templates for all the same reasons I don't use Haml when writing Ruby.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5653436/586748) on another question seems to suggest that you can use end tags if you want, but on the basic starter project I've set up on FP Haskell Center I can't get the code to compile if I add an end tag to anything other than a tag opened on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

Well the documentation seems clear enough:

> ... the only time you use closing tags in Hamlet is for inline tags; normal tags are not closed.

http://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates (end of Section "Tags")

Relevant source code: https://github.com/yesodweb/shakespeare/blob/master/hamlet/Text/Hamlet/Parse.hs#L558 functions `parseDoc`, `parseLines` etc.

the following shows that the first item (tag) in each line is treated specially,
while the others are just `ContentRaw`

```
ghci Text/Hamlet/Parse.hs
fmap (\(x,y,z)->z) $ parseLines defaultHamletSettings "<foo> <bar> @{oof} </rab>"

    ==> Ok [(0,LineTag {_lineTagName = "foo", _lineAttr = [],
          _lineContent = [ContentRaw " <bar> ",
          ContentUrl False (DerefIdent (Ident "oof")),ContentRaw " </rab>"], 
          _lineClasses = [], _lineAttrs = [], _lineNoNewline = False})]
```

so, hamlet will never actually notice whether a (inline) tag is closed.

still there could be a chance to switch to a "never close automatically" mode, and `closeStyle` in `nestToDoc` looks promising, but for non-empty contents, we always get `CloseSeparate`, implying that the closing tag will be inserted.

Comment: Yes, I thought there might be some optional, alternative way to use it as hinted in the linked answer.

Comment: Unlikely, according to my understanding of the source code, which I added to the answer.